# Create a Custom Ajax in form alter

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

Hi i have a problem to create a custom ajax, i have the following code.

the problem is i cannot make the code working no response nothing working for ajax callback, is simple but i try to put i src but still dont works, any help for make this to work, thanks

```
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerInjectionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerTrait;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface; 
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AppendCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function custom_form_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'node_comandas_edit_form' || $form_id == 'node_comandas_form') {

    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'custom_form/custom_form.library';

    foreach ($form['field_producto']['widget'] as $key => $value) {
      if (is_numeric($key)) {
        if ($value) {
          $valor_producto = $value['subform']['field_cantidad']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] * $value['subform']['field_precio']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'];
          $total += $valor_producto;
        }
      }
    }

    // Wrap textfields in a container. This container will be replaced through
    // AJAX.

    // This form is rebuilt on all requests, so whether or not the request comes
    // from AJAX, we should rebuild everything based on the form state.
    // Checkbox values are expressed as 1 or 0, so we have to be sure to compare
    // type as well as value.


    $form['field_total']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $total;
    $form['field_total']['#ajax'] = [
      // #ajax has two required keys: callback and wrapper.
      // 'callback' is a function that will be called when this element
      // changes.
      'callback' => '::custom_form_value_change',
      // 'wrapper' is the HTML id of the page element that will be replaced.
      'wrapper' => 'total-wrapper',
      'event' => 'click',
      'effect' => 'fade',
      'progress' => array(
        'type' => 'throbber',
        'message' => 'cargando',
      ),
    ];
  }
}

function custom_form_value_change($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $reponse = 'total-wrapper';
    //$response = new AjaxResponse();
    //$valor = 40000;
    //$response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('total-wrapper', $valor));
    return $response;
  }
```

(EDIT)

try other solutions but still dont working, i make this and works but with new fields, no with the existent of the node, i use paragraphs and also no working,some bug of drupal or use that i need?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function custom_form_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'node_comandas_edit_form' || $form_id == 'node_comandas_form') {

    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'custom_form/custom_form.library';

    foreach ($form['field_producto']['widget'] as $key => $value) {
      if (is_numeric($key)) {
        if ($value) {
          //$valor_producto = $value['subform']['field_cantidad']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] * $value['subform']['field_precio']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'];
          //$total += $valor_producto;
        }
      }
    }

    $form['field_total']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $total;
    $form['field_total']['#ajax'] = [
      // #ajax has two required keys: callback and wrapper.
      // 'callback' is a function that will be called when this element
      // changes.
      'callback' => 'custom_form_value_change',
      // 'wrapper' is the HTML id of the page element that will be replaced.
      'wrapper' => 'textfields-container',
      'event' => 'click',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ];

    $form['ask_first_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => 'Ask me my first name',
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => 'custom_form_value_change',
        'wrapper' => 'textfields-container',
        'effect' => 'fade',
      ],
    ];

    // Wrap textfields in a container. This container will be replaced through
    // AJAX.
    $form['textfields_container'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => ['id' => 'textfields-container'],
    ];
    $form['textfields_container']['textfields'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => "Generated text fields for first and last name",
      '#description' => t('This is where we put automatically generated textfields'),
    ];


    if ($form_state->getValue('ask_first_name', NULL) === 1) {
      $form['textfields_container']['textfields']['first_name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'First Name',
        '#required' => TRUE,
      ];
    }
    if ($form_state->getValue('field_total')) {
      $form['textfields_container']['textfields']['last_name_2'] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => 'Last Name 2',
        '#description' => t('This is where we put automatically generated textfields'),
      ];      
    }


  }
}

function custom_form_value_change($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $reponse = 'total-wrapper';
    //dpm($form_state);
    //$response = new AjaxResponse();
    //$valor = 40000;
    //$response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('total-wrapper', $valor));
    return $form['textfields_container'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The double colon (::) is used within classes, to indicate the current class. Hooks are not OOP (classes), they are procedural code. So you leave out the double colon:

```
  'callback' => 'custom_form_value_change',
```

Though I'd call it something more descriptive like `[module]_[form_id]_ajax_callback`.

Comment: same without :: no working, i try many other ways but no have difference no responding nothing, some in drupal 8 for break ajax?

Comment: That’s because you are not returning a valid response from your Ajax callback. You need to do some more reading about what you are supposed to return from an Ajax callback.

Comment: first i need to return a message that tell me it works with dpm but nothing

Comment: Yeah you wouldn’t see a dpm from an Ajax callback. Use the network inspector of the console.

Comment: hi i have new edit, you can see please, the example later of edit works, with custom fields, but no working with nodes fields

Comment: What are you getting for a response to the Ajax call  in the network panel of your console?

Comment: nothing, but if i make dpm in custom_form_value_change appear when i change somevalue in custom fields, in panel console appear changes, but no in fields of the node